# how to get the response api with status code is 400?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I consume api and when the api returns 200 status code, I return the response, but when the api returns 400 status code the api returns array with the errors, my questions is how can i get this array errors and return this array.

the code

```
try {
        const config = {
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/orders',
            headers: {'Key': '96db259b-2239-4abb-9b9d-a682a1de6b3c'}
        }
        const result = await axios(config)
        return result.data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error ' + error)
        returns result.data.errors
    }
```

this the response whit the status code is 400.

```
"errors": [
        {
            "value": "96db259b-2239-4abb-9b9d-a682ssa1de6b3c",
            "msg": "the API key 96db259b-2239-4abb-9b9d-a682ssa1de6b3c is invalid",
            "param": "key",
            "location": "headers"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
try {
        const config = {
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/orders',
            headers: {'Key': '96db259b-2239-4abb-9b9d-a682a1de6b3c'}
        }
        const result = await axios(config)
        if(result.status != 200) {
         throw new Error(`[Status ${result.status}] Something went wrong `);
        }
        return result.data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error ' + error)
        returns error.message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only do you need call the message attribute of error, for example:

```
try {
        const config = {
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/orders',
            headers: {'Key': '96db259b-2239-4abb-9b9d-a682a1de6b3c'}
        }
        const result = await axios(config)
        return result.data // this only called with success response, status code 200
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error ' + error)
        returns error.message;
    }
```